# How to format XDocument code to make it the most readable

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-xml

I've written a method to serialize a list (containing class objects) into an xml string, but with so many nests I can't figure out how to format my code to make it the most readable. Here's the xml example:

```
<Text>
    <Info name="example" language="en-US">example</Info>
    <Info name="example" language="en-GB">example</Info>
</Text>
```

And here's the (most likely) terribly formatted code:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument
    (
     new XElement
        ("Text",
            Infos.Select(item =>
                new XElement
                ("Info",
                    new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                    new XAttribute("language", item.Language),
                item.Value)
            )
        )
    );
return xdoc.ToString();
```

This is a fairly short example, but it may grow in the future and as such, I'd like to make my code the most readable - how do I do that here?

Comment: This question perhaps belongs more on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess that's something a moderator would be in place to decide, as I'm not able to delete and move this question seeing as it has already one answer. Still, if a mod decides to remove this question, it's his/her right to do so.

Comment: You should format it like you would a typical XML document would be formatted. The opening and closing tag would be on one indentation level, it's contents (attributes, values and other elements) would be on the next level. Here, that means the constructor call with name on one level, the other parameters (the contents) on the next level, then the closing parenthesis on the same level as the constructor (or if sufficiently short, at the end of the last item). Your approach is a huge departure from what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693049.aspx) suggests.

Comment: That link alone answers my question quite accurately, thank you for pointing it all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this format

```
//Option 1
XDocument xdoc1 = new XDocument();
xdoc1.Add(new XElement("Text",
    Infos.Select(item => new XElement("Info",
        new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
        new XAttribute("language", item.Language),
        item.Value
        )
    )
));

//Option 2
XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();
xdoc2.Add(new XElement("Text", new object[] {
    Infos.Select(item => new XElement("Info", new object[] {
        new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
        new XAttribute("language", item.Language),
        item.Value
    }))
}));
```

Comment: The main problem I see here is with `XElement`s not being aligned with its ending brackets. In case the xml expands in the future with new elements, will this code still be as readable?

Comment: I updated code to add a slightly different option.  Using a new object[] { adds a curly bracket which sometimes help make code more readable.